# How can I record voice from microphone in wave format in windows RT?

Tags: windows, windows-runtime, speech

I was able to get the file in mp3 and wma format. But I need wave format.

Comment: can any program like audacity be installed??

Answer (score 1):

I know this seems a bit twisted, but can't you install an audio-conversion software (or implement one, if the algorithm isn't too complex)?

Also, I'm not really familiar with this, but I've heard talk about `MediaEngine` for WinRT, if you don't know about it it might be worth looking into.

Comment: Formats are all proprietary -- wouldn't even be legal to implement one if I had the time, and the algorithm.